# How do I install PDF Mod?

Tags: software-installation

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and I can't find PDF Mod which is my favourite PDF-editing software.
I've downloaded the tarball from its website, extracted its contents, and
gone to the directory in terminal and run

`./configure`

but it told I needed
`gnome-doc-utils`.

This too I downloaded the tarball for and extracted. Then I tried to configure this by going to said directory and running

`./configure`

but I got this message:

```
error: Your intltool is too old.  You need intltool 0.35.0 or later.
```

So yet again I downloaded the tarball for the latest stable version of intltool (0.50), extracted its contents, went to its directory and ran
`./configure`

and while this worked with no errors I don't know what I'm meant to do now.

Comment: It must be in the Ubuntu 14.04 repositories as it's displayed when I enter **pdfmod** in the search box. I've got version **0.9.1-7 (trusty)** installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PDFmod is in Official Ubuntu Repository (packages.ubuntu.com). So you can easily install it using the following command ( Not other repositories or files needed):

```
sudo apt-get install pdfmod
```

Or

You can install it using Software center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 3):

Click this link to install [PDF Mod](http://tinyurl.com/lc4kas3) [image: Install PDF Mod] , find it in the Ubuntu Software Center, or type `sudo apt-get install pdfmod` in a terminal. There are more instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

After clicking on the link to install PDF Mod, it should open up the Ubuntu Software center, and all that you need to do is just press the install button, in red.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it on 14.04.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pdfmod
```

[image]

**Note:**

Whether you do just `sudo apt-get install pdfmod` or install from Ubuntu Apps/Software Center, you will end up with version 0.9.1.  Since The latest release is 0.9.1 released March 3, 2011.